# Is climate change already killing people and costing billions in the USA?

Tags: united-states, climate-change, public-health

[According to Gizmodo](https://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2019/09/in-the-us-climate-change-is-already-killing-people-and-costing-billions-in-medical-bills-report-finds/):

> Climate change will make our lives worse in the years to come, but a new report out last week highlights the stark costs people are already paying across the Atlantic. In 2012 alone, it found that in the US, 10 major climate-related events likely led to nearly 1,000 extra deaths, almost 21,000 hospitalisations, and an added $10 billion (£8 billion) in healthcare costs.

[The linked report](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2019GH000202) tots up effects and costs related to events influenced by climate events in 2012 (because that's the latest date where comprehensive medical records are available).

But there are some reasons to be skeptical of the estimates. One is that extreme climate events like hurricanes are common even without climate change (and the IPCC doesn't think they are *statistically* worse yet because of climate change). Also, a warming climate reduces deaths from cold as well as increasing deaths from heat (for those who doubt this: Excess winter deaths in the UK [average around 50,000/yr](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/birthsdeathsandmarriages/deaths/bulletins/excesswintermortalityinenglandandwales/2017to2018provisionaland2016to2017final) but the [biggest reported deaths from heatwaves](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-44956310) are in the low thousands; [Realclimate](http://www.realclimate.org/index.php/archives/2018/06/will-climate-change-bring-benefits-from-reduced-cold-related-mortality-insights-from-the-latest-epidemiological-research/) admits this general effect but argues, reasonably, that the effects may not be symmetric). And it isn't obvious whether the report has netted out either the lives saved from climate change or the baseline deaths that would have occurred even with no climate change.

So, is the *net* cost of climate change in the USA already billions in healthcare costs and perhaps 1,000 lives?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99208/discussion-on-question-by-matt-black-is-climate-change-already-killing-people-an).

Comment: My skepticism is that there's many reasons *not* climate change that could add 1000 deaths to climate disasters, starting with development over forests and water sheds, population increases, poor preparation, and bad government policy (see Katrina 2004 as an example). I'm sorry no good answer has come in yet.

Comment: It seems this is a really muddied topic. The primary issue is that climate-event-caused deaths have been steeply declining for decades. Trying to now account for climate-change-caused deaths seems quite undoable. This comment is based on numbers provided in [an op-ed on the WSJ](https://www.wsj.com/articles/climate-activists-disasters-fire-storms-deaths-change-cop26-glasgow-global-warming-11635973538).